# During FreeIPA setup: Forwarder does not respond

Tags: dns, ftp, docker

While trying to set up FreeIPA I get the following error:

```
The log file for this installation can be found in /var/log/ipaserver-install.log
==============================================================================
This program will set up the FreeIPA Server.

This includes:
  * Configure a stand-alone CA (dogtag) for certificate management
  * Configure the Network Time Daemon (ntpd)
  * Create and configure an instance of Directory Server
  * Create and configure a Kerberos Key Distribution Center (KDC)
  * Configure Apache (httpd)
  * Configure DNS (bind)

Warning: skipping DNS resolution of host ftpserver.mdrexl.net
The domain name has been determined based on the host name.

Checking forwarders, please wait ...
ipa         : ERROR    Forwarder 62.141.32.3 does not work
Forwarder 62.141.32.3 does not respond
FreeIPA server configuration failed.
```

I checked and found that the IP address is simply the first entry of my `/etc/resolv.conf`. And it is indeed the correct IP address of one of the specified nameservers as provided by the admin interface for my root server.

The origin of this setup is [this](https://github.com/adelton/docker-freeipa) docker container.